# regular expression to check text for date format not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a function to check a part of my html page for structure. I basically want to identify if div elements start with a date in the text/content or not. if so, then I would like to alter the HTML (but that is out of scope for this question.

My control is as followed:

```
function isDate(_date){
    const _regExp  = new RegExp('^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])?$');
    return _regExp.test(_date);
}

$(function() {
    var entries = $("div.histEntry");

    console.log('2018-08-01 18:30 is Date? ' + isDate('2018-08-01 18:30'));
    console.log('hungry like a wolf is Date? ' + isDate('hungry like a wolf'));

    $("div.histEntry").each(function( index, value ) {
      console.log('content of div: ' + $(this).text());
      console.log('text to check: ' + $(value).text().substring(0, 17));
      console.log('is Date?: ' + isDate($(value).text().substring(0, 17)));
    });

});
```

Here is a snippet from what I get returned in the console:

```
2018-08-01 18:30 is Date? true
hungry like a wolf is Date? false
content of div: 
2019-04-12 13:55 John Doe/Web/ACME created this document
text to check: 
2019-04-12 13:55
is Date?: false
content of div: 
2019-04-15 14:03 Office Manager changed from Jim Joe to Billy Boy
text to check: 
2019-04-15 14:03
is Date?: false
content of div: 
Mikael commented this document
text to check: 
Mikael commented
is Date?: false
```

Why is 2018-08-01 18:30 seen as date and 2019-04-15 14:03 not?

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` unless you're building the regexp dynamically, use a regexp literal.

Comment: `$(this).text()` begins with a newline, don't you see that in the console output?

Comment: Try using `$(this).text().trim()` to remove extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are testing a string that includes a white space at the end. Have you tried to check `$(value).text().substring(0, 16)`?. Just in case it's that simple.